# cuda 8.0 compatibility with nvidia-370 drivers

Tags: nvidia, graphics, cuda

I have a question I didn't find a direct answer to it on the forums. I have Kubuntu 16.04.1 64 bit installed. And I have Nvidia propitiatory drivers installed (nvidia-370). I installed Cuda 8.0 deb package from nvidia's website and I was trying to check the content of the package before installing Cuda.

Executing the command `dpkg -c cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb | grep 367` returns:

```
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     18834 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/libxnvctrl0_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root   2699418 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/libcuda1-367_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6408 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-352-updates-dev_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6414 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-libopencl1-361-updates_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root    866496 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-settings_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6402 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/libcuda1-352_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6424 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-opencl-icd-352-updates_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6390 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-352_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     16944 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-modprobe_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      2402 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/cuda-drivers_367.48-1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6408 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-opencl-icd-352_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root  69530338 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-367_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     84306 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/libxnvctrl-dev_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6410 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-361-updates-dev_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6410 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-libopencl1-352_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     82510 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-367-dev_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6420 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-libopencl1-352-updates_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6402 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-352-updates_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     19702 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-libopencl1-367_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6396 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-352-dev_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6408 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/libcuda1-361-updates_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6422 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-opencl-icd-361-updates_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6402 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-361-updates_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root   2847768 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/nvidia-opencl-icd-367_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6410 2016-09-24 00:10 ./var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/libcuda1-352-updates_367.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

You can notice the sub-packages having the number 367 (previous nvidia driver) in the file names.

But executing this command `dpkg -c cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb | grep 370` returns nothing.

Now does that mean Cuda 8.0 would cause problems with my current driver installed? The reason I'm asking is I want full Cuda compatibility and stable installation for my graphics card.

Please let me know if you want me to try anything for more information. Thank you very much for you assistance.